# minio deploy in docker login in got 'http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client' problem

Tags: docker, https, minio

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    container_name: minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: admin
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin123
      MINIO_SERVER_URL: "https://xxxx.ga:9000"
      MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: "https://xxxx.ga:9001"
      MINIO_COMPRESS: "off"
      MINIO_COMPRESS_EXTENSIONS: ""
      MINIO_COMPRESS_MIME_TYPES: ""
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./config:/root/.minio #where my certs locate
    command: server --address ':9000' --console-address ':9001' /data
    privileged: true
    restart: always
```

The service runs fine as I could see the login page and docker logs print the right address:

```
Status:         1 Online, 0 Offline. 
API: https://xxxx.ga:9000 
Console: https://xxxx.ga:9001 

Documentation: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/index.html
Warning: The standard parity is set to 0. This can lead to data loss.
```

minio docker version:RELEASE.2023-01-12T02-06-16Z (go1.19.4 linux/amd64)

Comment: The reason for this problem is that my hostname is incorrect. When I change it ended with ".com", I can login normally.  Still dont know why...